# How to prevent download video from server by using wowza streaming engine?

Tags: video, download, wowza

are there anyone used to work with Wowza. Please give me some solutions about: "How to prevent download video from server by using wowza streaming engine?" or "How to setting wowza streaming engine to prevent dowloading video from server?". I use default wowza player (do no use JWplayer). Thank you so much.

Comment: You want help ? Post what you've done and your code. We're not here to do your work for free.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't write clearly. I have setup wowza in window using wowza streaming engine trial. I also setting server and write some code to run video on demand sucessfully. But some download manager(like IDM) still can catch link and download video. I don't want user can download my video in server. I want to ask that wowza has solution to prevent download video. I have read wowza's documentation but i could not found something to protect my video from download manager

Comment: My bad then, but still i don't think there is something to do about it, you'll still have the link available client side at some point so it's most likely that you won't be able to prevent peoples who have access to your content from downloading it.

Comment: I understand. Are there any solution to encrypt the video content so that download manager still can download video but can not open it?

Comment: I'am not aware of such solution, but I don't think it's a good one either. Problem is, if you encrypt your video, you need to do it server side when it's uploaded right ? Then your user request the content so you give him the acces to the encrypted version AND you also need to decode it for him, be it server-side before letting him acces the content and you end up with the exact same situation: User still have access to the video, or you do that client side and one way or another  you'll still give him enough tools to work with so 3-party programs can still uncode and download your content.

Comment: In facts i don't even think there is a solution to your problem yet... this issue probably has been around for years now

Comment: yeah, I have searched many but have no solution zz. Thank you for your  response @xoxel